# Angular data table add button for each row

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I am using below library to my angular 16 project.
[https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome][1]

This is my function

```
  yes() {
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
  serverSide: true,
  pageLength: 5,
  dom: 'rtip',
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'user': 'testengagementpartner2@ssqa.com' // Replace with the actual username
    });
    dataTablesParameters.start = dataTablesParameters.start || 0;
    dataTablesParameters.length = dataTablesParameters.length || 10;
    this.http
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'http://10.183.84.30:8080/aqpp/getsSpecialistList',
        dataTablesParameters, { headers }
      )
      .subscribe((resp: DataTablesResponse) => {
        callback({
          data: resp.data,
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsFiltered,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,

        });
      });
  },

  columns: [
    {
      title: 'ID',
      data: 'id'
    },
    {
      title: 'Query Subject',
      data: 'querySubject'
    },
    {
      title: 'Actions',
      orderable: false, // Make the column not sortable
      data: null,
      defaultContent: '<button class="edit-button">Edit</button>'
    }
  ]
};
```

}

I tried to add action button for each column and when i click it, i need to pass row data to the button function. above function is not working. button did not appear.

this is my HTML

```
   <table datatable  [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped border"  style="width: 100%;"></table>
```

Comment: In the [examples](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/using-template-ref) you can see how add an action rows (see that use `ngTemplateRef`, **not** `defaultContent`. NOTE: Really I don't like so much [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) because force to install jQuery (but it's your election)